# How do I restore the “Inbox” label in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

After accidentally archiving all my mails, I have lost the “Inbox” label; how do I retrieve it?

Comment: this person is not talking about a message so much as the labels and management of the gMail web interface.  as the solutions may be a bit similar they are not the same question.

Answer (score -3):

In gMail, to manage your labels:

On the far right click the "gear".  Go down to "Settings"; click it.  A page will open up of which there will be a "label" tab; click it.  From here you can manage your labels.